# Добавление SearchView в toolbar. Почему getActioniew возвращает Null?

Tags: android, android-search-view

Все делаю по рекомендациям Google:
https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html?hl=ru
но в `onCreateOptionsMenu` получаю вместо `SearchView` `null`

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager =
        (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
        (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
        searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
}
```

Почему в этой строке :

```
SearchView searchView =
        (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
```

Я получаю NULL?

Comment: Попробуйте достучаться до SearchView в onPrepareOptionsMenu или вообще в onResume

Comment: решил заменой android на app в menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В меню:

Вместо `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"`

Использовал: `app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"`